# How to show Message box in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, messagebox

Can anyone please tell me about how to show message box in MVC application. I don't want to use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.
Additionaly i want to catch the response of button click e.g. If we press OK we should get a value. As it is in the case of System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.
Is there any way?

Thanks,
Kaps

Comment: You realize that you actually **can't** use the Forms message box in a web application, right?

Comment: Yes. Hence i want one using script.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function baked into JavaScript that you could use but it is pretty ugly and using something like the jQuery Dialog would probably be best.  Here it is anyway:

```
var answer = confirm("Are you sure");
```

Comment: Yes, but the buttons are "ok" and "cancel" and you can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript.
There are a lot of options out there (jQueryUI, ExtJS,etc), the simplest one is using javascript built-in prompt box.

function prompt()
{
var name=prompt("Please enter your name:","Your name");
//do your logic
}

Comment: How can i use it in controller of MVC application?

Comment: You will only use javascript in your View. If you want to send user input to server then you also have to create to create a controller action to accept your input